# Read CSV over SSH and convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, sftp, csvtojson

This is a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222176/nodejs-read-csv-file-from-sftp-server-and-convert-it-to-json)

Here is the code I'm trying to work with:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
var csv = require("csvtojson");

sftp.connect({
 host: 'HOST',
 port: 'PORT',
 username: 'USERNAME',
 password: 'PASSWORD'
}).then(() => {
 return sftp.get('/home/user/etc/testfile.csv');
  }).then((data) => {
   csv()
   .fromString(data.toString()) // changed this from  .fromStream(data)
   .subscribe(function(jsonObj) { //single json object will be emitted for each csv line
      // parse each json asynchronously
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       resolve()
       console.log(jsonObj);
    })
   })
 }).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

I can read back the CSV data, and can see it going into JSON format on console.log(jsonObj) but the data is unreadable, all '\x00o\x00n\x00'' ..

I'm not sure what to do in the line:
// parse each json asynchronously

Could anyone help to figure out how to parse the CSV/JSON after it comes back from the buffer?

Comment: "can see it going into JSON format" - so the JSON structure is correct, it's just that the strings in it contain the null byte `\x00` in various places?

Comment: Yes, the JSON structure appears to be fine {\x00},{\x00},{\x00}. .. So I don't think the JSON part is the issue, its the null bytes. I'm not sure how to get that Buffer to display the actual correct values back from the remote CSV

Comment: I guess this is an encoding issue. I think the csvtojson tool uses utf8 and your file might be something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null bytes `\x00` are pointing towards an encoding/decoding issue. The CSV file might be encoded using UTF-16, but [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) by default decodes the data using UTF-8. You can change that to `data.toString('utf16le')` (or `data.toString('ucs2')`) to force using the correct encoding.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Formatting is all wrong, but that's another issue :)